# Deleting a name from a text file in Python

Tags: python, file, random

Can someone check the code for me? I have three set of codes. The first part draws a random name from a file, name.txt and then displays it. The second code copies the drawn name into another file name2.txt and the third code is suppose to delete the drawn name from the first file. this is where I'm struggling to get it right. any help would be appreciated.

```
  import random

  #File path    
  g = r"C:\Users\Homer\name.txt"  
  lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open(g)]

  #draw a random word  
  rand = random.choice(lines)

  # Display random word 
  print(rand) 

  # Append random word to name2.txt 
  with open("name2.txt",'a') as k:
        k.write(rand)
        k.write("\n")
        k.close()

  # Delete random word from orignal file (name.txt)
  g = with open("name.txt",'w')      
  lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open(g)]        
  g.pop(rand)
```

Comment: `g = with open("name.txt",'w')` ?? I don't even know what it does but why not reusing the same syntax as above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `g` without `with`, then use `lines.remove` and remove `rand`, then use `writelines` to write it back:

```
...

g = open("name.txt",'w')      
lines.remove(rand)
g.write('\n'.join(lines))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Code working good. Please how can I tell this code g.writelines(lines)  to write one name per line when writing back into name.txt. its working okay just that it writes all names on one line with no space. Thank you so much

Comment: @Homer Edited mine.

Comment: Many thanks. All working great

Comment: @Homer Happy to help, :-)